# Resize node pool instance/node type on aks with basic sku

Tags: kubernetes, azure-kubernetes-service

I have a kubernetes cluster on aks (Azure kubernetes) with a basic load balancer (hence I cannot have multiple node pools).

The normal procedure to [resize node pools in Kubernetes is well documented by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/resize-node-pool?tabs=azure-cli), however that does not work when you have a basic load balancer. The azure cli command to create the new node pool will then output the following error message:

```
az aks nodepool add --resource-group rg --cluster-name k8s --name single --node-count 1 --node-vm-size Standard_B2ms --mode System --no-wait
(SLBRequiredForMultipleAgentPools) Basic load balancers are not supported with multiple node pools. Create a cluster with standard load balancer selected to use multiple node pools, learn more at aka.ms/aks/nodepools.
```

Is there a way I can change the node instance type with this setup? I don't mind if the entire cluster is down during the change, but I'd like to avoid setting up a completely new cluster of course.